# TouchDevelop Deleting text

Tags: text, touchdevelop

**The Issue:**

- I have two buttons, button "Apple" and button "Cookie".
- When I press the "Cookie" button, text should show saying "Cookie" on screen (which it does)
- THEN, when I press the "Apple" button, the text should UPDATE to "Apple" instead of "Cookie"

The problem is, with my current code, whenever I press the second button (Apple) -- the original "Cookie" text isn't removed, it appears underneath the "Apple" text.

I'd like the "Cookie" text to be removed from the screen when I press the apple button or any other button (over 10 buttons)

How would I achieve this within touchdevelop?

**Current Code:**

[image: http://imgur.com/XAbMeIX]

---

Assistance is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try this project: http://tdev.ly/ydcl.

To change what is displayed when a button is clicked, set a global variable and change its value when `on tapped` is called.  In TouchDevelop, the page display is refreshed automatically so that any changes made when a button is tapped will occur immediately.  There is no need to `hide` or `show` part of the display; just include that section in an if statement and change the if statement condition when a button is tapped.  If you wanted to show one of three possible layouts, use an if statement that tests the value of a string or number for one of three values and changes that value when a certain button is tapped or condition is met.